# How can I download my Ubuntu One data using a PowerMac G5, Mac OS X 10.5.8 (or a rooted Nexus 4 + remote fs)

Tags: ubuntu-one, mac, powerpc, nexus-4

I need to download my Ubuntu One data using a PowerMac G5 Early2005 DP 2.0GHz, Mac OS X 10.5.8 (or a rooted Nexus 4 8GB with real *total* storage 5.37GB). How should I do that?
Thanks in advance,
Michał Krzysztof Feiler

Previously I've asked on reddit:
http://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/2b2vg3/i_need_to_download_my_ubuntu_one_data_using_a/

Comment: http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/2014/06/03/moving-your-content-away-from-ubuntu-one-file-services/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download the G5 powerPC image of Ubuntu [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04/release/),
2. Make a bootable USB.
3. Boot to the live USB and install Ubuntu One.
4. Copy your files to another HDD/USB or dropbox.

Failing that find a friend with Windows/Ubuntu and use their computer to install Ubuntu One. You must act fast however as **you only have until 31st July 2014** before file services are terminated (see [this link](https://one.ubuntu.com/shutdown/)).